# Calculate Percentage in array using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to calculate the  10%  from total array  of values
for eg

```
perc = [56,50];
function percentage(perc) {
  return (perc / 100) * 10;
}
```

Comment: What does that mean - are you trying to get 10% of the sum of the values in the array? Something else?

Comment: 10% from sum of the values

Comment: Well step 1: sum the values, step 2: multiply by 0.1.

Comment: You first need to sum the values using a loop of some sort or using an array method like reduce

Comment: You're not doing anything to get the sum.

Answer (score 2):

You need to first sum the array, and then calculate 10% of that sum:

```js
function percentage(perc) {
  const sum = perc.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)
  return sum * 0.1;
}
```

Comment: Excellent. I have edited the question, to make clearer what the questioner wanted. I couldn't understand the question until I read your answer!